# App aware Bluetooth BLE communication between Android and Iphone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create an app on iOS that need to send/receive small parts of data for another app, on another phone (eg. Android) using the Bluetooth Low Energy protocol.

I know that it is possible between two iOS devices. But, and with Android?

Answer (score 1):

Android device can act as `central` (meaning they can connect to BLE advertising devices) but cannot act as `peripheral` (meaning they cannot advertise BLE services).

So you can actually communicate by BLE between an iPhone and an Android devices (the iPhone being used as `peripheral`, and Android as `central`) but you cannot do so between 2 Android devices.

Comment: Good! But i can send any kind of data? Because im didn't understand the part of ATT/GATT. For me, it is only the predefined values? [Android Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#terms)

Comment: @andresmafra I'm afraid you might have to open a new question if you have more specific question about Android and BLE. It's been like 3 eternities since the last time I played with Android and BLE (like, 6 whole months I think) and for what I remember, you can send "whatever" you liked (if it's too big, you can always send your data split in many packets). The best practice though is to transmit the smaller packets possible, so bitmasks are your best friend.

Comment: From Android version 5.0+ Android device act as both central and peripheral